# Show values in y axis in thousands

Tags: d3.js, yaxis

I have a scatter plot graphic in d3.js where y values range from 0 - 160,000.
How could I show value in y axis like 0-160 and an axis subtitle clarifying that values are in thousands?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format).

Comment: # locale.formatPrefix(specifier, value) . This is the command I should use. k (for kilo, i.e. 10ˆ3) is the specifier. Could anybody please show me an example of how to write the correct syntax? Thanks

Comment: You don't need `d3.format` or `locale` here. Just put this in your axis generator: `tickFormat(function (d){ return ~~(+d/1000)})`.